# Manejo de listview y sqlite instancia

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite, listview

Vengo con un pequeño problema en mi aplicación, uso android studio para el desarrollo, lo que sucede es que tengo 3 actividades:

- En **EleccionSE** yo al elegir una opción por medio de un `spinner` y por `checkbox`, genero una consulta que la guardo en una variable tipo String.
- En la actividad **Lista**, se genera un `Listview`
- En **BasedeConocimiento** esta guardada toda la base de datos de la aplicación

El problema que tengo (y se que es muy sencillo pero aún no tengo claro cómo hacerlo y me ha dado problema por un largo tiempo) es que al generar mi consulta en EleccionSe, como puedo enviarla a la actividad Lista, necesariamente como la estoy haciendo, la frase tiene que llegar a Lista y luego esta envía la consulta a la base de datos.

¿Cómo podría yo enviar esa consulta? les agradezco infinitamente quien pueda ayudarme :D

Aquí les dejo las partes de mis actividades:

Actividad **EleccionSE**

```
public class EleccionSe extends AppCompatActivity {

String[] TipoTierra= {"Arcilloso","Arenoso","Franco","Franco arenoso","Franco arcilloso","Franco limoso","Frnaco arcilloso arenoso"};
String [] TipoClima= {"Frio","Moderadamente frio","Templado","Moderadamente calido","Calido","Caliente"};
Spinner SpinnerTipotierra;
Spinner SpinnerClima;
TextView Temperatura;
String Ciudad;
TextView Fecha ;
String Celsius,Mes;
double tempCelsius;
String SeleccionClima;
String SeleccionTierra;
CheckBox Cundinamarca;
CheckBox Boyaca;
CheckBox Nariño;

Button boton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_eleccion_se);

    Cundinamarca = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.Cundinamarca);
    Boyaca = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.Boyaca);
    Nariño = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.Nariño);
    Temperatura = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Temp);
    boton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.BotonSE);

    SpinnerTipotierra=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.SpinnerTierra);
    SpinnerClima=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.SpinnerClima);
    CargaSpinner();


    LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    EleccionSe.Localizacion Local = new EleccionSe.Localizacion();
    Local.setUbicacion(this);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, (LocationListener) Local);
    TextView Temperatura = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Temp);
    //final String temp = (String) Temperatura.getText();
    //final Double tempe = Double.parseDouble(temp);

    // Fecha Mes
    final String[] monthname = {(String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MMMM", new Date())};
    Fecha = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Fecha);
    Fecha.setText(monthname[0]);
    Mes = Fecha.getText().toString();
    //final int Mesfinal = Integer.parseInt(Mes);
    //cierre mes
    SpinnerClima.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), parent.getItemAtPosition(position)+ "es seleccionado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            SeleccionClima= parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), SeleccionClima+ " clima es seleccionado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
    SpinnerTipotierra.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), parent.getItemAtPosition(position)+ "es seleccionado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            SeleccionTierra = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), SeleccionTierra+ " tierra es seleccionado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });

    RealizarConsulta();

}

public void CargaSpinner(){
 ...
}

public void setLocation(Location loc) {
    ...
}

public class Localizacion implements LocationListener {
    ...
}

private class OpenWeatherMapTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

   ...
}




public void RealizarConsulta(){

     boton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.BotonSE);
    boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {

            if (Mes.equals("mayo")) {
                tempCelsius = Double.parseDouble(Celsius);
                Lista consulta = new Lista("Select * from Hortaliza_Verdura");

                Intent cambia = new Intent(EleccionSe.this, Lista.class);
                startActivity(cambia);

            }

      }

   });


} 
}
```

Actividad **Lista**

```
public class Lista extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView lv;
ArrayList<String> Lista1;
ArrayAdapter adaptador;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista);

    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lista);
    poblar();

}

   public void poblar(){
    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lista);

    Lista1 = bd.llenar_lv("aqui va la consulta a la BD");
    adaptador = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Lista1);
    lv.setAdapter(adaptador);

}


}
```

Actividad **BasedeConocimiento**

```
public class BaseDeConocimiento extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

ListView lv;
ArrayList<String> Lista1;
ArrayAdapter adaptador;


public BaseDeConocimiento(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version)
{

    super(context, "AppAgroKB", factory, 1);
}


public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "Creando base de datos");

    db.execSQL( "CREATE TABLE Hortaliza_Verdura(Nombre_Hortaliza TEXT,Departamento TEXT,Temperatura Integer,Clima_Optimo TEXT,Tipo_Suelo TEXT,Mes_Optimo TEXT,Conclusion TEXT)");



    Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "Tabla Hortaliza_Verdura creada ");
 /*
  * Insertamos datos iniciales
  */

    Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "Datos base de conocimientos");

    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Hortaliza_Verdura(Nombre_Hortaliza, Departamento, Temperatura, Clima_Optimo, Tipo_Suelo, Mes_Optimo,Conclusion) VALUES('Cebolla Cabezona','Boyaca','Entre 18 y 22','Templado','Arcilloso','febrero','La mejor opcion para esta epoca es sembrar cebolla cabezona')");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Hortaliza_Verdura(Nombre_Hortaliza, Departamento, Temperatura, Clima_Optimo, Tipo_Suelo, Mes_Optimo,Conclusion) VALUES('Cebolla Cabezona','Boyaca','Entre 18 y 22','Templado','Arcilloso','marzo','La mejor opcion para esta epoca es sembrar cebolla cabezona')");


    Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "Base de conocimientos creada");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Hortaliza_Verdura");
    onCreate(db);


}

public ArrayList llenar_lv (String query) {


    ArrayList<String> Lista1 = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor registro = database.rawQuery(query,null);

    if(registro.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            Lista1.add(registro.getString(0));
            /*Lista1.add(registro.getString(1));
            Lista1.add(registro.getString(2));
            Lista1.add(registro.getString(3));
            Lista1.add(registro.getString(4));
            Lista1.add(registro.getString(5));
            Lista1.add(registro.getString(6));*/

        }while (registro.moveToNext());
    }

    return Lista1;



}
```

}

Comment: Hola Daniel, tengo algunas dudas. Cual es tu objeto `bd`. Donde dice tu texto "aqui va la consulta" que espera la funcion `llenar_lv` ?

Comment: Hola sioesi, hace un tiempito encontré un tutorial de como usar sqlite y listview, ese llenar_lv está en la actividad BasedeConocimiento, allí es donde llega la consulta y empieza a hacer la busqueda, muchas gracias por tu respuesta :)

Comment: Puedes agregar esa clase a tu codigo? No entiendo aun que es lo que falla o te falta

Comment: sioesi, ya he agregado toda la actividad Basedeconocimiento y alli esta `llenar_lv` para que quizas entiendas lo que quiero hacer es, en EleccionSE se crea esa consulta, digamos si estamos en el mes de mayo entonces la consulta sera `select * from..` esta se guarda en un string y la enviamos a la actividad Lista, alli se usaria ese String en donde esta el objeto `bd.llenar_lv (String)` ya luego se hace la consulta y devolveria la respuesta dentro del listview :D muchas gracias por tu ayuda sioesi

Comment: Daniel, tienes una CLASE llamada lista? es un objeto?

Comment: Es una clase sioesi, que ahi es donde se hace la actividad del listview :3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes de redireccionar en `EleccionSe` debes crear la consulta :

```
String consulta = "Select * from Hortaliza_Verdura";
Intent i = new Intent(EleccionSe.this, Lista.class);   
i.putExtra("consulta", consulta);
```

Y en la Activity `Lista`

```
String consulta = "";
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras == null) {
    consulta = null;
} else {
    consulta = extras.getString("consulta");
}
```

Comment: dejame ya lo pruebo a ver como anda, y en la Activity `Lista`, en mi objeto `bd.llenar_lv` debo poner la variable consulta? para que esta realice la consulta cierto? muchisimas gracias por toda tu ayuda :D

Comment: como te fue @DanielRios ??

Comment: Es que aún no llegó a mi casa del trabajo y no he podido probarlo sioesi

Comment: Hola sioesi, te confieso que al principio no entendi la funcion del `Bundle extras`  y todo lo que tenia que ver con el `Intent`
Lei acerca de esto y me ha corrido de maravilla, solo tengo palabras de agradecimiento hacia ti y decirte que me has ayudado totalmente, mil millones de gracias, estoy muy contento y si te tuviera al lado te daba un abrazo de agradecimiento amigo, muchisimas gracias, haz hecho a un programador novato a ser feliz :D

Comment: Un abrazo @DanielRios! me alegro que se haya solucionado todo!